# Google analytics filtering data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm reasonably new to google analytics. The site I am trying to analyse though is very big and has a lot of dynamic content.

To try and make my job easier I've made a filter to mash all the times users viewed their own profiles into one number rather than counting each one seperately. The trouble is...I can't check if I've done this filter right as it is working as a new copy of the analytics for my 
page, it didn't take the old data with it and I will have to wait until tomorrow for it to fill with a days's worth of data.

What I wonder is, is the anyway to make filters that take pre-existing data with them and merely change it? Or are filters doomed purely to filter incoming
data and what has gone before is untouchable?

Comment: It's the latter - filters do not work on data already collected. Nothing you could do about it.

Comment: any way to check if my filter is working the way I intend it?
I usually script with a heavy amount of trial and error (Its not my main speciality) and having to wait a day to see the outcome is a bit of a pain.

Comment: 1) Check in realtime view, 2) keep an unfiltered profile for backup and comparison, 3) keep a test profile for new filters - many filters now have a preview that tells you how many % of your data would be affected by the filter.